# Save an array of objects in mongoDB and escape double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save an `array` of `objects` from node to **MongoDB**.

I use:

```
    _id: ObjectID(request.body.connectionId)
}, {
    $set: {
        status: accepted,
        networks: connectedProfiles
    }
```

but at **MongoDB** record i get:

```
"networks": "\"(\\n        {\\n        netowrk = TWITTER;\\n        \\\"profile_name\\\" = primary;\\n    }\\n)\""
```

Any idea why i get the `escape` quotes?

Comment: try to debug `connectedProfiles` if it is string or object.

Comment: Yeah, connectedProfiles doesn't even look like it's a serialized array. How do you build op that variable?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I finally fixed this issue by stringify the request before sending it to node js, and after parse it. This solved the problem.